# Powershell: Functions with switches that include arguments

Tags: function, powershell, windows-7, parameters

So I'm trying to write a script that uses switch parameters and I also need arguments to go along with them. So for instance,

```
Function Foo ($X, $Z, [switch]$Y, $Yarg, [switch]$K, $Karg){
  if($Y){
    $Yup = $Yarg
  }

  if($K){
    $Y = $Karg
  }Else{$Y = 42}

  $X + $Z / $Yup

}
```

Essentialy I want to ask if the switch is there, then if it's there I want it to use the $Yarg variable, currently when I do that I get an error saying the switch can only be a boolean value. Then the rest of the code fails. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My assumption is that Y and K are mutually exclusive parameter sets, and X and Z are common to both, and mandatory. If neither -Y nor -K are specified, the default will be -Y. I'm using the alternate parameter declaration syntax here for clarity:

```
function Foo(
    [cmdletbinding(defaultparametersetname="setY")]
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        $X,

        [parameter(mandatory=$true)]
        $Y

        [parameter(parametersetname="setY")]
        [switch]$Y,

        [parameter(parametersetname="setY", mandatory=$true)]
        $YArg,

        [parameter(parametersetname="setK")]
        [switch]$K,

        [parameter(parametersetname="setK", mandatory=$true)]
        $KArg,
    )
    # do work
)
```

I'm hoping the syntax should be obvious.

Comment: This pushed me much further along, but now I'm stuck again.

Comment: Ok, so this worked pretty well, it just ended up being a matter of the parameter types I was using. I didn't really need to use Switches for the most part. It was more so using unmandatory variables. so instead of the above code I used this:

`function Foo(
    [cmdletbinding(defaultparametersetname="setY")]
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)]
        $X,

        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=1)]
        $Y

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        $Y,

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        $K,
    )
    # do work
)`

Thanks for the help!

Comment: ah, so you were confusing -parameterName:parameterValue with switches. These ain't switches; they're "named parameters." Switches don't have arguments (unless you explicitly provide a Boolean like -myswitch:$true or -myswitch:$false).

Answer (score 0):

So what I am intending on doing is making a function where you enter variables like so

```
foo x z -y yarg -k karg
```

Primarily wanting the **-y yarg** type variable entry.

For me to be able to do this I thought I needed to use a switch, but really I just needed unmandatory parameters.

```
   function Foo(
    [cmdletbinding(defaultparametersetname="setY")]
    param(
        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=0)]
        $X,

        [parameter(mandatory=$true, position=1)]
        $Z

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        $Y,

        [parameter(mandatory=$false)]
        $K
    )
    # do work
)
```

That seemed easier, and it works!